# I need to access Dropbox folders from my android app, select a file and open it in my app

Tags: android, dropbox

I need to access Dropbox folders from my android app, select a file and open it in my app.
How to do it? I have used API for authentication. MB it needs to start some dropbox's activity for result, but how to catch selected file? Thx for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's all you need to do, I would suggest using [the Chooser](http://dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/android).